# Datasheet issue with more than 500 entries.[Sharepoint foundation 2010 ]

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint portal where users add their daily tasks. Different view are created basted on the practices.

When entries in datasheet exceed 5000, sharepoint gives error to user. I understand that 5000 is the limit set by central admin and I don't want to raise this limit.

My questions here are

1. Is this limit of 5000 entries is at list level of view level, if its on view level will it be then possible to create two different view with 4000 entries each?
2. How to achieve this in sharepoint foundation 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5000 throttle limit is view limit (administrators have 20000 items limit by default). As you mentioned you can change it in central administration but it's not good practice as it has relation to SQL table locking strategy (when more than 5000 rows are read from SQL table, table is completely locked and all other data requests are hold).

You can create multiple views with less than 5000 items but you can not use them together in single datasheet view.

This issue has no relation to Foundation/Server question.